# Grails custom test - No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.phase.IntegrationTestPhaseConfigurer.prepare()

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I'm trying to follow Luke Daley's instructions on http://ldaley.com/post/615966534/custom-grails-test to add a custom test type, which should behave as an integration spec (grails-2.4.4, btw).

I've put my specs under test/apint and my _Events.groovy loooks like below:

```
eventAllTestsStart = {
    phasesToRun << "apint"
}

def apintSpecsSuffix = "spec"
def apintSpecsDirectory = "apint"
def apintSpecsTestType = new GrailsSpecTestType(apintSpecsSuffix, apintSpecsDirectory)


apintTests = [apintSpecsTestType]


apintTestPhasePreparation = {
    integrationTestPhasePreparation()
}

apintTestPhaseCleanUp = {
    integrationTestPhaseCleanUp()
}
```

When I run `grails test-app apint:` I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error running tests: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.phase.IntegrationTestPhaseConfigurer.prepare() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: prepare(groovy.lang.Binding, java.util.Map), prepare(groovy.lang.Binding, java.util.Map), grep(), grep(java.lang.Object), every(), println() (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
.Tests FAILED
```

Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix it?

Thanks!